# Writing pseudocode

Tags: algorithms, algorithmic

Consider the following trivial pseudo-code that I am trying to execute while using \usepackage{algorithm}
and \usepackage{algpseudocode}

```
\begin{algorithm}[H]
    \caption{name}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \State {\bf Input:}
    \end{algorithmic}\label{hello}
\end{algorithm}
```

- At the "State" it produces a "Missing \endcsname inserted" error
  (and this error shows up on almost every next State that I have tried putting in here!)
- At "\end{algorithmic}" it produces an error "missing number treated as 0"

Can someone kindly help?

Comment: There must be something else you're including/doing, since I can't recreate your issue using [this minimal example](https://pastebin.com/raw/YwMvz8Qi).

Comment: Do you have guesses for where can I go looking? I have no clue!

Comment: Can you provide your complete preamble? Everything from `\documentclass` to `\begin{document}`.

Comment: Thats a huge file! It would be a complete mess to try pasting that here. Its some 250 lines there. I can summarily say that it is in the "svjour3" class which on its own loads a "\RequirePackage{fix-cm}" and additionally I am loading packages like, amsmath,amssymb,amsxtra,mathtools, array,parskip,graphicx,algorithm, algpseudocode, dsfont, verbatim,enumerate,graphicx, color, hyperref

Comment: Try your code with minimal preamble. If it works (as the other comments seem to suggest), add your preamble bloc by bloc, to see where the error comes from.

Comment: @gradstudent: *You* will have to reduce the code in such a way that makes it manageable for us to consume. Otherwise, you have a problem that we can't diagnose. Read this: [I've just been asked to write a minimal working example (MWE), what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764)